# android holo light what is the background color

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="18"

In theory simple thing. What is the background color for holo.light as I want to use the same color for something else? It's not white neither background_light. Moreover my question is not how to determine its value but what android predefined constant to use (as if one day google change this light background color in holo light, my color would also change).

Btw, transparent color is not the solution in this case. :(

Answer (score 10):

```
<color name="background_holo_light">#fff3f3f3</color>
```

You can find this by using the awesome chrome extension Android Resource Navigator.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/android-resource-navigato/agoomkionjjbejegcejiefodgbckeebo

You should be able to use @android:color/background_holo_light or android.R.color.background_holo_light  I think.

Comment: But when I try to use it, ex. when defining shape <solid android:color="@android:color/background_holo_light"/> I got the information error:resource is not public. :((

Comment: Ah. That's a shame.  There are a lot of them like that.  In that case, you just have to use the color value, then update it in the future as needed :(

Answer (score 2):

I tried

```
<color name="background_holo_light">#26f3f3f3</color>
```

It's the right color for the background Holo light Theme